# TensorFlow: List index out of range with conv2d_transpose

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I would want to use a convolution transpose to obtain a tensor of 2700 values with the following input:

```
input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, 1 , 1 ,1))
```

To do that, I used the [tf.nn.conv2d_transpose](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d_transpose) function.

Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

import numpy as np

sess = tf.Session()

batch_size = 20

input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, 1 , 1 ,1))

logits = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(input, [batch_size,1,2700,1],[batch_size, 1, 2700, 1],[1,1,3,1],'SAME')
```

When I run this program, I have the following error on the last line :

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here is the complete error returned by Python:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-724f7880c01d> in <module>()
      9 input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, 1 , 1 ,1))
     10 
---> 11 logits = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(input, [batch_size,1,2700,1],[batch_size, 1, 2700, 1],[1,1,3,1],'SAME')

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py in conv2d_transpose(value, filter, output_shape, strides, padding, data_format, name)
   1223     filter = ops.convert_to_tensor(filter, name="filter")  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
   1224     axis = 3 if data_format == "NHWC" else 1
-> 1225     if not value.get_shape()[axis].is_compatible_with(filter.get_shape()[3]):
   1226       raise ValueError("input channels does not match filter's input channels, "
   1227                        "{} != {}".format(value.get_shape()[axis],

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    610         return TensorShape(self._dims[key])
    611       else:
--> 612         return self._dims[key]
    613     else:
    614       if isinstance(key, slice):

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Some help would be welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of [tf.nn.conv2d_transpose](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d_transpose) you can see that you need to **define placeholders** for `filter` and `output_shape` similar to how you did for `input`.

The following test code ran for me without returning an error. Make the necessary changes for the output size you need:

```
import tensorflow as tf

import numpy as np

sess = tf.Session()

batch_size = 20

input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, 1 , 1 ,1))

filter = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, 1 , 2700 ,1))

out = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(4,))

logits = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(input, filter,out,[1,1,3,1],'SAME')
```